# In FullCalendar in react Error Uncaught TypeError: view.computeEventDraggable is not a function

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working with fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io) in react, my problem is when I create an event in the week view and try to go to the monthly view the console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: view.computeEventDraggable is not a function
    at TimeGridEventRenderer.renderSegHtml (main.esm.js: 155)
    at TimeGridEventRenderer.FgEventRenderer.renderSegEls (main.js: 9531)
    at TimeGridEventRenderer.FgEventRenderer.renderSegs (main.js: 9486)
    at TimeGrid.res [as renderFgEvents] (main.js: 3911)
    at TimeGrid.render (main.esm.js: 628)
    at TimeGrid.Component.receiveProps (main.js: 4802)
    at SimpleTimeGrid.render (main.esm.js: 1427)
    at SimpleTimeGrid.Component.receiveProps (main.js: 4802)
    at TimeGridView.render (main.esm.js: 1563)
    at TimeGridView.Component.receiveProps (main.js: 4802)
    at CalendarComponent.renderView (main.js: 7639)
    at CalendarComponent.render (main.js: 7549)
    at CalendarComponent.Component.receiveProps (main.js: 4802)
    at Calendar.renderComponent (main.js: 8298)
    at Calendar.executeRender (main.js: 8250)
    at Calendar.tryRerender (main.js: 8227)
    at Calendar.requestRerender (main.js: 8218)
    at Calendar.dispatch (main.js: 8201)
    at Calendar.changeView (main.js: 8538)
    at HTMLButtonElement.buttonClick (main.js: 7389)
```

my declaration of fullcalendar looks like this

```
<FullCalendar
    defaultView="dayGridMonth"
    header={{
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
    }}
    rerenderDelay={10}
    eventDurationEditable={false}
    editable={true}
    droppable={true}
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
    ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
    weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
    events={this.state.calendarEvents}
    eventDrop={this.drop}
    drop={this.drop}
    eventReceive={this.eventReceive}
    eventClick={this.eventClick}
    dateClick={ this.handleDateClick }
/>
```

I would very much appreciate some help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by downloading the bookstore version:

Initial version `"@ fullcalendar / interaction": "^ 4.3.0"`. Version that worked `"@ fullcalendar / interaction": "4.2.0"`.